# Is this a effective way to delete entire linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

In function given below, I simply delete the head-pointer of the list and set head pointer to `nullptr` (im setting it `nullptr` because in my print function,I check for `nullptr` for head node, and ask user to create list first if head-node is `nullptr`).

```
void del_list(stud* &orig_head)
{
    cout << "Deleting entire list..." << endl;
    delete orig_head;
    orig_head = nullptr;
}
```

I have a question regarding the way I choose to delete the list, since im not clearing each node of list, im simply clear the head pointer, what will happen to all the other nodes? Will this approach create a memory leak ?

Edit:

Im not using OOP to implement linked list,im implementing linked list using struct and couple of functions.

Comment: Memory leak? Yes.

Comment: Why do you need a `del_list` function to begin with? Looks like you should take a step back and learn proper memory management with RAII.

Comment: @DeiDei Exactly what i expected, thanks!

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thank you for your comment, I need del_list function to clear the list...Now that I know my approach will create memory leak, I will iteratively go over the list and delete all nodes!

Comment: @calculusnoob Why in an extra function, though? That functionality belongs in the destructor.

Comment: The point is, with class like `std::unique_ptr`, you don't even need to iterate the list.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Actually, im not using Object Oriented approach, Im implementing linked list on my own using struct and a couple of functions :)

Comment: @calculusnoob That's... not a good idea, but have fun I guess.

Comment: @BaummitAugen Thank you for your feedback but im implementing my own linked list for the sake of learning. I know we have `std::list` :)

Comment: Deleting just the head pointer is not correct. You will leak all the rest of the nodes in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to handle this problem recursively:

```
void deleteNode(Node * head)
{
    if(head->pNext != NULL)
    {
        deleteNode(head->pNext) 
    } 
        delete head;
}
```

If we have a list of 5 items:

head->pNext->pNext->pNext->pNext->NULL;

Then, the function will first get called for head, then for each pNext until the last one. When we reach the last one, it will skip deleting the next one (since it's null) and just delete the last pNext. Then return and delete the list from back to front.

This is assuming that each node's pNext is initialized to NULL. Otherwise, you'll never know when you've reached the end of the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will cause memory leak. To delete it correctly, traverse the list and while traversing delete each node separately. And finally make head pointer to point to NULL value. You can have a look at the following code.

```
void deleteList(struct Node** head_ref) 
{ 
   struct Node* current = *head_ref; 
   struct Node* next; 

   while (current != NULL)  
   { 
       next = current->next; 
       free(current); 
       current = next; 
   } 
   //Now make head_ref point to null
  *head_ref = NULL; 
}
```